Question about weighted means (V.Zorich Mathematical Analysis 1 Chapter 5.4.6 Ex. 1)
Let $ \mathbf{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) $ and $ \boldsymbol{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n) $, where $ x_i \geq 0 $, $ \alpha_i > 0 $ for $ i = 1, \ldots, n $, and $ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1 $. For any number $ t \neq 0 $, we consider the mean of order $ t $ of the numbers $ x_1, \ldots, x_n $ with weights $ \alpha_i $:
$ M_t(\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^t \right)^{1/t}. $
In particular, when $ \alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = \frac{1}{n} $, we obtain the harmonic, arithmetic, and quadratic means for $ t = -1, 1, 2 $, respectively.
Show that:
(b) $ \lim_{t \to +\infty} M_t(\mathbf{x}, \boldsymbol{\alpha}) = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i. $
How do I show this exactly? I can see intuitively that expression on the right is like upper bound of values of M for increasing values of t, but how do you prove it?

It suffices that $\alpha_i>0.$ Other assumptions are not essential. Let $x_j=\max x_i$ and $\alpha =\max\alpha_i.$ Then  $$\alpha_j^{1/t}x_j\le M_t(x,\alpha)\le (n\alpha)^{1/t}x_j$$ By the squeeze rule the limit of $M_t(x,\alpha)$ is equal $x_j.$

This is clear when each $x_i = 0$, so we may assume some $x_i > 0$.
We are going to apply a useful idea: take advantage of homogeneity in the $x_i$'s to reduce to the special case where the maximum is $1$.
By homogeneity in the $x_i$'s I mean that for $c > 0$,
$$
M_t(c\mathbf x,\boldsymbol{\alpha}) = cM_t(\mathbf x,\boldsymbol{\alpha})
$$
and
$$
\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} cx_i = c\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i.
$$
By using $c = 1/\max(x_1,\ldots,x_n) > 0$, we can reduce the general task to the special case when $\max_{1 \leq i \leq n} x_i = 1$: some $x_i$ is $1$ and all $x_i \leq 1$.
When $0 \leq x_i < 1$, $x_i^t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$. Therefore
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^t  = \sum_{\{i : x_i = 1\}} \alpha_i > 0.
$$
Set $S = \sum_{\{i : x_i = 1\}} \alpha_i$ and pick $0 < \varepsilon < S$.
Since $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^t \to S$ as $t \to \infty$, for all large $t$ we have
$$
0 < S - \varepsilon < \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^t < S+\varepsilon.
$$
Take $t$-th roots: for all large $t$,
$$
0 < (S - \varepsilon)^{1/t} < \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i^t\right)^{1/t} < (S+\varepsilon)^{1/t}.
$$
For each positive number $a$, $a^{1/t} \to 1$ as $t \to \infty$. Therefore by letting $t \to \infty$ in the above displayed inequalities with $t$-th roots,
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_ix_i^t\right)^{1/t} = 1.
$$
